# Unable to get specified image size in WordPress custom post development using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to add image sizes for normal post and in archive post specified two different sizes but it is not working properly. I have added code below used in functions.php and in archive, single.php below. Please check and help me. Thanks in advance...!!

In functions.php:

```
<?php
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');

add_image_size('smallest',300,300,true);

add_image_size('largest',800,800,true);
?>
```

In single.php (normal post):

```
<?php if(has_post_thumbnail()):?>
    <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('largest');?>" class='img-fluid'>
<?php endif;?>
```

In archive.php:

```
<?php if(has_post_thumbnail()):?>
    <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('smallest');?>" class='img-fluid'>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Did you rebuild your post thumbnails after adding these new sizes to your site? Keep in mind that when you add new image sizes to WordPress only images you upload afterwards will create a thumbnail for the new registered sizes. That's the reason why we have plugins such as [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) for example.

Comment: After adding code for image sizes I have added the featured images. I am trying to add custom code without using any plugins(Regenerate Thumpnails) @cabrerahector.

Comment: I did it after replacing the code with other wordpress default functions instead of calling largest and smallest....and added below 

<?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?>

Comment: Ok so what exactly is the problem you're having then? Are images showing in a different size? Are they not showing up at all?

Comment: I have solved it using other wordpress function now it looks good, yes the image size not shown as mentioned in the funtions.php for smallest and largest but fixed using above line in between if statement instead of calling smallest or largest @cabrerahector